# Kласс DataOutputStream: при записи данных в файл там абракадабра символов. В чём проблема?

Tags: java, io

Пример работы класса DataOutputStream для записи данных в файл:
https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.7.php

Код работает, но в файл почему то какая-то абракадабра из символов записывается.
В чём тут дело? Что надо ещё сделать? Или это у меня одного так?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Такое происходит у всех. Все дело в том, что в файл нельзя просто так взять и записать примитив.

Он записываются в понятном виде для компьютера, но мы люди понимаем его очень плохо.

К примеру, если `boolean` `true` оно запишется, как `1`, а если в противном случае `0`.

Для того чтоб записать `int` сначала получается его побитовое значение и записывается. Такое же происходит с `long`, `short`.

Ну а байты просто записываются. Ничего особого.

Чтоб записать `float` он сначала представляется с соответствии с битовой маской «одиночный формат» с плавающей точкой IEEE 754, те. в виде `int`. Далее он записывается метод `writeInt ()`.

Такое же происходит с `double`, но уже с `long`.

Строка записывается следующим способом. Строка перебирается по символу и символ записывается. Нужно учитывать, что управляющие символы также учитываются.

### Итог

И тут не надо ничего придумывать. Просто следует использовать `DataInputStream` и радоваться жизни.